# Chain methods and call function one by one

Tags: javascript, algorithm

so basically I need to implement a lazy evaluation. .add() takes a function as parameter and any other arbitrary arguments. The function that is passed as an argument is run later (when evaluate is called) with other arguments(if any) as parameters to that function.

Basically my issue stands when i run .evaluate() which takes an array as parameter, the functions that were passed to add() as parameters are not called one at a time and returning a result and have it as a parameter for the next.

```js
class Lazy {
  constructor() {
    this.functions = [];
    this.counter = 0;
    this.resultedArray = [];
  }

  add(func, ...args) {
    if (args.length > 0) {
      this.counter++;
      const argsArrayNumeric = args.filter((item) => typeof item === "number");

      this.functions.push({
        func: func,
        args: args,
      });
    } else {
      if (func.length <= args.length + 1 || func.length === args.length) {
        this.counter++;
        this.functions.push({ func: func });
      } else {
        console.log("Missing parameters for " + func.name + " function");
      }
    }
    return this;
  }

  evaluate(array) {
    if (this.counter > 0) {
      let result;

      this.functions.map((obj, index) => {
        array.map((item, index) => {
          console.log(obj);
          if (obj.func && obj.args) {
            result = obj.func(item, ...obj.args);
          } else {
            result = obj.func(item);
          }
          this.resultedArray.push(result);
        });
      });
      console.log(this.resultedArray);
    } else {
      console.log(array);
    }
  }
}

const s = new Lazy();

const timesTwo = (a) => {
  return a * 2;
};
const plus = (a, b) => {
  return a + b;
};

s.add(timesTwo).add(plus, 1).evaluate([1, 2, 3]); 
//correct result is [3,5,7] but i have [ 2, 4, 6, 2, 3, 4 ]
```

Comment: The result of `const argsArrayNumeric = args.filter((item) => typeof item === "number");` is unused. It looks like you want `this.functions.push({ func, args: argsArrayNumeric });`

Comment: Yes,but that does not answer my question. The thing is that i am chaining. so for each chain i should be evaluating the array with the function that i added to .add() function

Comment: `args.length` is `0` in the `else` block. It's confusing to not write `if (func.length <= 1 || func.length === 0) {`. I don't even understand the expected result. I expect `[(1 + 1) * 2, (2 + 1) * 2, (3 + 1) * 2]`. What does `func.length` even mean? When does a function have a `length`?

Comment: You're calling `this.functions.map` but you're ignoring the result. Do you mean `this.functions.forEach`? The same with `array.map`. One of your problems is in `result = obj.func(item, ...obj.args);` and `result = obj.func(item);`. You're not passing the previous result to the function call.

Comment: The actual output is `[2, 3, 4, 2, 4, 6]`. The first three elements are `1 + 1, 2 + 1, 3 + 1` (first function applied) and the second three elements are `1 * 2, 2 * 2, 3 * 2` (second function applied).

Comment: Thanks for your answer jabaa. "The actual output is [2, 3, 4, 2, 4, 6]. The first three elements are 1 + 1, 2 + 1, 3 + 1 (first function applied) and the second three elements are 1 * 2, 2 * 2, 3 * 2 (second function applied)." That's right, but I would like to have the result from the first function applied, and then apply the second function to that result. That is the main problem here.

Comment: @jabaa `Function.length` is an integer indicating the number of named arguments of the function, and has been around since ES1.

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) _StackOverflow is a question-and-answer site for specific questions about actual code; “I wrote some buggy code that I can’t fix” is not a question, it’s a story, and not even an interesting story._

Comment: You could initialize `result` with the `item` and pass `result` instead of `item`.

Comment: what do you mean? could you send the script please?

Comment: No, sorry. It's probably over my head ;-)

Comment: Whatever mate..

Comment: In your comment in the code example you say you want `[3, 5, 7]`, but I would read the code as "First `plus`, then `timesTwo`", which would not produce your desired result. Do you want the functions to be applied in the order they are added, or in reverse?

Comment: Oskar, yes, my bad. It should be in the order they are added, so using reduce like trincot's answer does the job.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few problems in `evaluate`:

- `push` will be executed too many times when you have more than one function.
- Don't use `map` when you don't really map. `.map()` *returns* a result.
- From the expected output (in the original version of the question) it seems you need to apply the functions from right to left, not from left to right.
- `this.counter` does not really play a role. The length of the `this.functions` array should be all you need.
- the result should not be printed in the method, but returned. It is the caller's responsibility to print it or do something else with it.

All this can be dealt with using `reduce` or `reduceRight` (depending on the expected order) like this:

```
evaluate(array) {
    return this.functions.reduceRight((result, obj) => 
        result.map((item) => obj.func(item, ...(obj.args || [])))
    , array);
}
```

And in the main program, print the *return* value:

```
console.log(s.add(plus, 1).add(timesTwo).evaluate([1, 2, 3]));
```

The `add` method has also some strange logic, like:

- When the first `if` condition is false, then the `else` block kicks in with `args.length == 0`. It is then strange to see conditions on `args.length`... it really is 0!
- If the first condition in `func.length <= args.length + 1 || func.length === args.length` is false, then surely the second will always be false also. It should not need to be there.
- `argsArrayNumeric` is never used.

All in all, it seems the code could be reduced to this snippet:

```js
class Lazy {
    constructor() {
        this.functions = [];
    }

    add(func, ...args) {
        if (func.length > args.length + 1) {
            throw ValueError(`Missing parameters for ${func.name} function`);
        }
        this.functions.push({ func, args });
        return this;
    }

    evaluate(array) {
        return this.functions.reduceRight((result, obj) => 
            result.map((item) => obj.func(item, ...(obj.args || [])))
        , array);
    }
}

const timesTwo = (a) => a * 2;
const plus = (a, b) => a + b;

const s = new Lazy();
console.log(s.add(plus, 1).add(timesTwo).evaluate([1, 2, 3])); // [3, 5, 7]
```

Comment: Clean, thank you!

Comment: Nice!  My first snippet is much the same as this, except for the arity guard.  Speaking of that, though, shouldn't that test go before the `push`?  It's recoverable, and the existing Lazy instance is still usable, but it won't be after that `push`.

Comment: Yes, swapping those instructions is better. Done.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're working too hard at this.  I believe this does almost the same thing (except it doesn't report arity errors; that's easy enough to include but doesn't add anything to the discussion):

```js
class Lazy  {
  constructor () {
    this .fns = []
  }
  add (fn, ...args) {
    this .fns .push ({fn, args});
    return this
  }
  evaluate (xs) {
    return xs .map (
      x => this .fns .reduce ((a, {fn, args}) => fn (...args, a), x)
    )
  }
}

const timesTwo = (a) => a * 2
const plus = (a, b) => a + b

const s = new Lazy () .add (timesTwo) .add (plus, 1)

console .log (s .evaluate ([1, 2, 3]))
```

But I don't actually see much of a reason for the `class` here.  A plain function will do much the same:

```js
const lazy = (fns = [], laze = {
  add: (fn, ...args) => lazy (fns .concat ({fn, args})),
  evaluate: (xs) => xs .map (
    x => fns .reduce ((a, {fn, args}) => fn (...args, a), x)
  )
}) => laze

const timesTwo = (a) => a * 2
const plus = (a, b) => a + b

const s = lazy () .add (timesTwo) .add (plus, 1)

console .log (s .evaluate ([1, 2, 3]))
```

This is slightly different in that `s` is not mutated on each `add`, but a new object is returned.  While we could change that and mutate and return the original object easily enough, the functional programming purist in me would actually consider moving more in that direction.  In fact, all we're maintaining here is a list of `{fn, args}` objects.  It might make the most sense to take that on directly, like this:

```js
const add = (lazy, fn, ...args) => lazy .concat ({fn, args})
const evaluate = (lazy, xs) => xs .map (
  x => lazy .reduce ((a, {fn, args}) => fn (...args, a), x)
)

const timesTwo = (a) => a * 2
const plus = (a, b) => a + b

const q = []
const r = add (q, timesTwo)
const s = add (r, plus, 1)

// or just
// const s = add (add ([], timesTwo), plus, 1)

console .log (evaluate (s, [1, 2, 3]))
```

In this version, we don't need a `Lazy` constructor or a `lazy` factory function, as our data structure is a plain array.  While this is the format I prefer, any of these should do something similar to what you're trying.

### Update

Based on comments, I include one more step on my journey, between the first and second snippets above:

```js
const lazy = () => {
  const fns = []
  const laze = {
    add: (fn, ...args) => fns .push ({fn, args}) && laze,
    evaluate: (xs) => xs .map (
      x => fns .reduce((a, {fn, args}) => fn (...args, a), x)
    )
  }
  return laze
}

const timesTwo = (a) => a * 2
const plus = (a, b) => a + b

const s = lazy () .add (timesTwo) .add (plus, 1)

console .log (s .evaluate ([1, 2, 3]))
```

This version may be more familiar than the second snippet.  It stores `fns` in a closure, hiding implementation details in a way we often don't with JS classes.  But that list is still mutable through the `add` method of the object we return.  Further ones proceed down the road to immutability.

Comment: Interesting alternatives!

Comment: (Paraphrased) "I don't see much reason to use `class` here": Sure, you can code-golf here, but using a `class` makes the code generally more understandable (for the average coder). There is almost always a way to use old patterns, but classes were added mostly as syntactic sugar, to make code easier to understand and maintain.

Comment: Why return a parameter with a default value if you can instantiate an object in the function-body? Misusing the parameter this way will backfire if two arguments are provided.

Comment: @OskarGrosser: I had many steps along the way to the final version here.  I probably should have posted one without using the parameters in that manner, but as the main point was to get to final version, I didn't think it through.  I do use this approach a great deal, but usually not in public functions like `lazy`.

Comment: @OskarGrosser: the point wasn't code golfing at all.  I know why `class` was added to the language, and fought against it because it was trying to pretend that JS OO was closer to Java/C# OO than it really is; changing the surface but hiding the internals.  The point, though, was immutability.  Using a mutable class when an immutable design works just as well always scares me.

Comment: @OskarGrosser.  [One intermediate step](http://link.fourwindssoft.com/35) avoids those parameters, but hasn't gotten to immutability.

Comment: Broken link. I just guess you meant closures, which I think are unnecessary in this situation. In my opinion, making the functions-array a property of your `lazy` would be beneficial in case `lazy` needs to be used in a _slightly_ modified way.

Comment: Hmm, I edited the link right after posting it.  Is it still broken?  Because it works for me.

Comment: Yes, some of the intermediate steps had functions which closed over the list of `{fn, args}` objects.  But the goal was the final step.

Comment: I've added that snippet as an update to the answer.